# Google Maps base map definition

Tags: wms, google-maps, coordinate-system, openlayers-2, basemap

I need to replace a 'Global Imagery' basemap in Google Maps.

However if I replace it with "Openlayers.Layer.Google", that would use map projection of EPSG:3857 (900913). But I'm working with EPSG: 4326.

This is how the Global Imagery is defined:

```
       layers: [ 

new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Global Imagery (OpenGeo) [Online]",
                        "http://maps.opengeo.org/geowebcache/service/wms", {
                            layers: "bluemarble"
                        },{

                            isBaseLayer: true,
                            visibility: false
                        }
                    )

]
```

Is there a way to replace it into Google Maps with EPSG:4326, while keeping the same definition structure?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you're asking, but so far as I know Google *Maps* only uses 3857. I seem to recall reading something about anything in 4326 (WGS84) sent to it was automatically converted, though it was suggested to do that on your own. Note that Google *Earth* uses 4326.

Answer (score 1):

i faced somehow the same problem. For me that worked. instead of EPSG:4326 in my project i used EPSG:28993.

```
mapOptions = {projection:"EPSG:900913",displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")};
map = new OpenLayers.Map(mapOptions);
googleBaseMap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Satellite", {'type' : google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID});
map.addLayers([googleBaseMap]);
```